# OnBindViewholder Not Returning Exact Position After Scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to replicate YouTube's Homepage view with a horizontal scroll at the top for the trending topics and then a set of card views to show the videos with a footer view to show home, subscriptions and the lot.

I am using a `Recyclerview` with a Header which again has a `RecyclerView` where for the top scrolling of the trending topics and a fixed `LinearLayout` at the bottom for the footer. (Not fixed at the bottom but added at the last position for now).

**Issue & Initial Findings**

I want to have a custom header view at the 1st position (Array Index - 0) and another custom footer at the 7th position (Array Index - 6). My issue is that when I initially load the app, I can see that `onBindViewHolder` is calling the positions from 0 to 6 and when I scroll down all the way, all the views are showing fine but when I move up, I can see that there are 3 empty positions added in the positions of 1,2 and 3 and it's showing a plain white screen but I can actually see those 1,2 and 3rd items (along with the remaining as well) below the plain white space which means that a new 1,2 and 3rd position with plain white space popped up after the scroll. It's completely weird and I am not doing any actions in any of the `RecyclerView` items as well and making no changes dynamically.

I would much appreciate anyone pointing out any dumb mistakes that I might be doing.

**Main screen with fully loaded views when I first open the app**:

[image: Main Screen With Fully Loaded Views]

**Main screen with empty views at positions 1,2 and 3 after scrolling**:

[image: Main Screen With Empty Views]

I have a fragment where I set the `RecyclerView` and that specific code is as follows (I am not sure if one would need this to find the issue but just in case)

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_primary_screen, container, false);
recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_listview);
mainScrollAdapter = new MainScrollAdapter(context,repeaterClasses,top_scroll_item_array);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(mainScrollAdapter);
mainScrollAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
return rootView;
```

Here is my Main Adapter class for the main `RecyclerView` which has the header & footer

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v;
        this.VIEW_TYPE = viewType;

        switch (viewType)
        {
            case VIEW_TYPES.Header:
                Log.e("Inside","Header");
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_view,parent,false);
                break;

            case VIEW_TYPES.Footer:
                Log.e("Inside","Footer");
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.footer_view,parent,false);
                break;

            default:
                Log.e("Inside","Others");
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.youtube_video_item,parent,false);
                break;

        }

        BaseViewHolder myViewHolder = new BaseViewHolder(context,v,mYoutubeVideos,top_scroll_items);
        return myViewHolder;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.onBind(position);
        Log.e("OnBindVIewHolder",""+holder.getAdapterPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Log.e("getItemViewType",""+position);
        if(position==0)
            return VIEW_TYPES.Header;
        if(position==7)
            return VIEW_TYPES.Footer;
        else
            return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       return 7;
    }


    private class VIEW_TYPES {

        public static final int Header = 0;
        public static final int Footer = 6;
    }
```

My `BaseViewHolder` that extends the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class whose `onBind` method is as follows

```
public void onBind(final int position) {
        switch(position) {

            case VIEW_TYPES.Header:
                top_scroll_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
                top_scroll_recycler_view.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                top_scroll_recycler_view.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL) {
                    @Override
                    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
                        // Do not draw the divider
                    }
                });
                top_scroll_recycler_view.setAdapter(new TopScrollAdap(context,top_scroll_items));
                break;

            case VIEW_TYPES.Footer:
                break;

            default:
                Log.e("The current position is ",""+position);
                if(position<6)
                {

                Log.e("The current position is ",""+position);
                final YouTubeVideoRepeater youTubeVideoRepeater = youTubeVideoRepeaters.get(position);
                ((Activity)itemView.getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

                if(youTubeVideoRepeater.getTitle()!=null)
                    textWaveTitle.setText(youTubeVideoRepeater.getTitle());
                else
                    textWaveTitle = null;

                if(youTubeVideoRepeater.getImage_url()!=null)
                    Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(youTubeVideoRepeater.getImage_url()).apply(new RequestOptions().override(width-36,200)).into(imageViewItems);
                else
                    Glide.with(imageViewItems).clear(imageViewItems);

                imageViewItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                youTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        imageViewItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        youTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReady(YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                                super.onReady(youTubePlayer);
                                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(youTubeVideoRepeaters.get(position).getVideo_id(),0);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });


                }

                break;
        }

    }


    private class VIEW_TYPES {

        public static final int Header = 0;
        public static final int Footer = 7;
    }
```

**Update: Disabling the Headerview resolves the issue but I don't understand why it is happening.**

The Adpater for the `RecyclerView` in the header is as follows

**TopScrollAdapter**

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public TopScrollAdap.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_view_item,parent,false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TopScrollAdap.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        viewHolder.top_scroll_list_item.setText(top_scroll_items.get(position));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return top_scroll_items.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        TextView top_scroll_list_item;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            top_scroll_list_item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.top_scroll_list_item);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What happens is that you need to create a condition that restores the view to an original state. Remember that RecyclerView uses dirty views to form new views, so "Recycle". Then, in the onBindViewHolder, whenever you have an if, you must put an else condition, which cleans the state of that view. For example, let's say you want to paint a red button if a condition x and the original color of the view is blue. If you never put an else condition to paint the blue button again, you will surely use a red button to create a new view, but since there is no condition that restores the view to blue.

Comment: Let me see if I get it, you're using an recycler view within another recycler view representing the Header item and you're setting up this Header Recycler view inside onBind method? It seems wrong to me, maybe it works, but I don't see a reason to do that. Also, use I would rather use ListView for small lists with fixed size, it probably would fix you issue just moving to ListView

Comment: On the switch, you have a default statement. This sentence modifies views if the position is less than 6, but you do nothing when the position is Footer. Therefore your views will be loaded with dirty data. All of your if conditions must have an else, so you can restore the views to their original states. `if(youTubeVideoRepeater.getImage_url ()! = null)` for example, it will load an image if it exists, but if it does not exist you should clean the ImageView, because otherwise you could create an element of the RecyclerView from that dirty view and it will show you a data that you don't want

Comment: @Andrespengineer I tried what you had told but I am not sure if I'm doing it right. I have updated the code as well so please check it.

Comment: @Andrespengineer for some weird reason, removing the header seems to be resolving the issue but I don't know why it's working in the first place. Your thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why in adapter  Footer = 6 and in ViewHoler  Footer = 7? (and in general why you create inner classes just for a constants)

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii thank you for pointing it out, I will enhance my code as per your comments.

Comment: You have an itemCount of 7. The range of positions is from 0 to 6. You have a condition in the ViewType that says `if (position == 7)`, so when it is 6 it will return position and not the Footer. This will create a "Normal" view and there is no condition that modifies it, because in your onBind in switch default, you have if (position <6), it never enters if it is 6. Simply put, when the position is 6, enter to switch default and does nothing, just create a default view. Try changing the viewType condition to if (position == 6) and let me know.

Comment: @Andrespengineer no luck in changing the position to 6 and moreover, removing the header is making it all right so I can't seem to understand why is that !

Comment: @San Well I'm for sure that you hide your mistake from us

Comment: We need full code of adapter, full code of viewholder and xml file to find out. There is a lot of mistake and bad approach in code that you attach but non of them can't just remove whole viewholder.